# Handle sqlite database in searching

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

in my app searchbar is there, wheren in user types the text. Whenever a text get changes in the filed i will call a query to DB to get the related search items. But sometimes it crashes.

Here is the code i'm doing to call DB

```
                @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(newText.trim().equals(""))
                {
                   return false;
                }


                //showSearchSuggestions(newText);
                mfilterdata = mController.get_controllerObj().getDBManager().getAllSuggestedFilter(newText);

                if(mSearchadapter != null)
                mSearchadapter.swapCursor(mfilterdata);


                return false;
            }
```

Here is how i m querying in DB manager

```
    public Cursor getAllSuggestedFilter(String filterString)
{
       String READ_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + Tbl_ITEM_TABLE + " where "+ 
                            item.TITLE + " Like" + "\"%" + filterString + "%"+"\"";

       if(mcursorForFilter != null)
       {
           mcursorForFilter.close();
           mcursorForFilter = null;        
       }

       try
       {
          mcursorForFilter = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(READ_QUERY, null);
       }
       catch(Exception ee)
       {

       }


       return mcursorForFilter;
}
```

randomly i get exception like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT * FROM itemtable where title Like"%t%")
```

Comment: why -1?? can u justify?

Comment: Ok, but i get this exception i.e attempt to re-open an already-closed object. is this because of my query syntax?

Comment: ok, i did so, and also randomly i will be typing the text, so each and every time it needs to perform the query and fill my adapter. so if my adapter is still filling and query is already performed i get crash perhaps. any idea how to fix this?.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you are closing the cursor in the wrong place, and trying to use it after that, but you cannot use an already closed cursor.

I would get rid of this part of the code:

```
if(mcursorForFilter != null) {
   mcursorForFilter.close();
   mcursorForFilter = null;        
}
```

Instead, close the old cursor after you set the new one. `swapCursor()` returns the old `Cursor`, or returns `null` if there was not a cursor set, also returns `null` if the if you try to swap the same instance of the previously set cursor. Knowing that, you can try something like this:

```
Cursor c = mSearchadapter.swapCursor(mfilterdata);

if(c != null)
    c.close();
```

Try that, and let me know if that helped.

**Note** that when you are using a Loader (LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks), the framework is going to close the old cursor. This is what the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) says:

> onLoadFinished:
>
> The loader will release the data once it knows the application is no
>   longer using it. For example, if the data is a cursor from a
>   CursorLoader, you should *not call close()* on it yourself. ...

Comment: Hi, Thanks.  i tried your technique, but the crash behaviour is minimized. But still i do get that crash. Is there any other technique we can use to query the database and display suggestions?. Also i noticed while typing text in edittext, i feel lag in my keyboard, may be because of repeated db calls, how to prevent?

Comment: IS there a way, we can load full data i.e Select * from Atable and filter based on the text. I have tried like that in string arrayadapter but not on cursor adapter.